# How to reformat the directories names?

Tags: shell-script

I have many directories with the names as following
`geom1 geom10 geom11 geom12 geom13 geom14 geom15 geom16 geom17 geom18 geom19 geom2 geom20 geom3 geom4 geom5 geom6 geom7 geom8 geom9`

I would like to rename them to be like this

`geom0000001 geom0000002 geom0000003 geom0000004 geom0000005 geom0000006 geom0000007 geom0000008 geom0000009 geom0000010 geom0000011 geom0000012 geom0000013 geom0000014 geom0000015 geom0000016 geom0000017 geom0000018 geom0000019 geom0000020`

I used the following script

```
a=1 for  
i in geom*/; do
          new=$(printf "geom%07d" "$a") 
            mv -- "$i" "$new"
              let a=a+1
      done
```

the problem, it moves for examples `geom10` to  `geom0000002` not to  `geom0000002` while `geom2` to `geom0000012` not to `geom0000002`

what I want is to renames the directories with the same sequence but with the new format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
for i in geom*
do
      new=$(printf "geom%07d" "${i##geom}") 
      echo  "$i" "$new"
 done
```

where

- `##geom` construct will remove geom from var.
- replace `echo` by `mv` if satisfied

Comment: What is more amazing is that OP haven't accepted this answer.

Comment: that is frequent....lots of "hit&run" around here, and yes, nice answer

Comment: acceptation can come latter on, as well as upvote, I still get some once in a while from my answer to a vi question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a recommended solution, but it works. I suggest that you only use it in the above mentioned specific case. It is not recommended to loop over `ls` results. If you have other folder names, or you want to use it in a more general situation, then you should find another solution.

```
for i in geom*; do 
  nr=$(echo $i | cut -d'm' -f2); 
  #printf "geom%07d" "$nr"; 
  mv "${i}" "$(printf "geom%07d" "$nr")"
done
```